# Why am I getting undefined output Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I keep getting undefined before my output text in JS.
Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Learning javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="arrayString"></p>



    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS

```
var arrayString;
var myArray=["Ms.Vickies", "Old Dutch", "Lays"];
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    arrayString=arrayString+myArray[i];
}
document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML=arrayString;
```

my output is `undefinedMs.VickiesOld DutchLays`

In addition why no spaces? I am new to JS but am working my way up. Cannot figure this out.

Comment: To allow people to easily help you, consider making a jsfiddle of your problem. jsfiddle is a site where you can run javascript with html live in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

It's because in your first loop iteration, `arrayString` is undefined.  Set it equal to an empty string instead.

Instead of declaring `arrayString` like so:

```
var arrayString;
```

Initialize it with an empty string:

```
var arrayString = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initiating a null/undefined variable by doing this: `var arrayString;`

You can fix it by doing this: `var arrayString = "";`

Better yet, instead of using a `for` loop, you can do it like this:

```
var myArray=["Ms.Vickies", "Old Dutch", "Lays"];
document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML = myArray.join(" ");
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

In code ,you have just declared,not initialized.so,just replace

```
  var arrayString;
```

with

```
 var arrayString = '';
```

Hope it helps...Thank you.